# Is it possible to use gradient + background color for areaColor along with visualMap

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, visualization, geo, echarts

thanks for your time!
[I am using a similar example to visualize my data](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=map-usa-projection).
I want to improve the visualization of the map and make a gradient. [More or less like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XXmR.png). After reading the documentation, I realized that apparently this is not possible:

```
inRange: {
 color: [
  new echarts.graphic.RadialGradient(0.5, 0.5, .5, [
   {
    offset: 0,
    color: 'green'
   },
   {
     offset: 0,
     color: 'rgb(35, 184, 116, 0.2)'
   }]), 
   'rgba(255, 88, 74, 0.7)'
   ]
}
```

I tried to play around with overlaying two equivalent series and different settings for them, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. By adding a gradient like this.

```
const mapOptions = {
series: [
  ...,
  {..., itemStyled: {..., areaColor: gradient}},
 ] 
}
```

And I already created the information panel manually and added functionality through

```
mapInstance.setOptions(newSeriesOption)
```